# Error building in TeamCity

Tags: msbuild, teamcity

While building a project in TeamCity I get this error.  Any idea why?

```
[15:05:04]Step 2/2: Web Admin (MSBuild) (6s)
[15:05:07][Step 2/2] x.Admin\x.Admin.csproj.teamcity: Build target: Build (4s)
[15:05:11][x.Admin\x.Admin.csproj.teamcity] CoreCompile
[15:05:11][CoreCompile] Csc
[15:05:11][Csc] CSC error CS2001: Source file 'HomeController.generated.cs' could not be found
[15:05:11][Csc] CSC error CS2001: Source file 'SharedController.generated.cs' could not be found
[15:05:11][Csc] CSC error CS2001: Source file 'T4MVC.cs' could not be found
[15:05:11][x.Admin\x.Admin.csproj.teamcity] Project x.Admin\x.Admin.csproj.teamcity failed.
[15:05:11][Step 2/2] Step Web Admin (MSBuild) failed
```

I have selected the option in TeamCity to always do a clean checkout.

Comment: Well have you had a look in TeamCity's 'work' directory, to see what it's built? Have you built locally, using a *fresh* `checkout` of your repository, using the *same* profile, targets & configuration? Has this *suddenly* started happening? Running the latest version? Have you tried clearing it's 'work' directory and forcing it to do a clean checkout?

Comment: I've built locally, using all the same configuration.  This is a new build that I'm creating so this is a new problem.  It is using the latest code.  I'll clear the work directory now and try.

Comment: @Arran deleting all the data in work does fix the issue.